# How to derive from RDD and create your own?

Tags: python, apache-spark

We have our own proprietary format for storing polygon and shapes in an image. I would like to use Spark to process this format. Is it possible to create my own reader in SparkContext to read the proprietary format and populate RDDs? I would like to create a derived class of existing RDDs which would be populated by my reader in SparkContext. I would like to do this in Python. Any suggestions or links is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to create own reader? Sure. Just implement custom Hadoop Input Format. Is it possible in Python? No. You can read complete files and parse these later.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to simply read the data and convert it to an RDD using your Spark Context. You can then action on the data using Spark.

Example:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val result : RDD[MyCustomObject] =
  sc
    .parallelize(Source.fromFile("/tmp/DataFile.csv")
    .getLines()
    .drop(1)
    .map(x => MyCustomObject(x))
```

This applies to any format of data - although if you're able to read from HDFS, Cassandra, etc. the data will be read via distributed read and presented as an RDD.

Comment: `parallelize` is no a very useful approach. If you want to suggest reading complete files then `wholeTextFile` / `binaryFiles`